# unable to login in stackops

Tags: linux, cloud

I have new installation of stackops distribution. When I tried logging into the stackops portal with user information "head/stackops"(as described in the documentation) , but it says "invalid user". 
i have checked the mysql database for portal, where the users database is empty.

how to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Go on and hack it. GIYF on how to gain root access via a Linux LiveCD.

Comment: i already have root access, tried to populate the database with required entries, but still there are some settings, which i am not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Try with 'portal/stackops'. 'head' is the default user for Enterprise version of the product.

Comment: even this one did not workf... checked that the database for the users is empty.